# Getting NSDictionary keys sorted by their respective values

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I have an `NSMutableDictionary` with integer values, and I'd like to get an array of the keys, sorted ascending by their respective values. For example, with this dictionary:

```
mutableDict = {
    "A" = 2,
    "B" = 4,
    "C" = 3,
    "D" = 1,
}
```

I'd like to end up with the array `["D", "A", "C", "B"]`. My real dictionary is much larger than just four items, of course.

Comment: There are dozens of elements, I want a new array of Keys sorted by the ascending values of the keys that contain integers

Comment: Josh, for what I'm trying to do, yes they are all integers. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `NSDictionary` Method `keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:` should do the trick.

You just need a method returning an `NSComparisonResult` that compares the object's values.

Your Dictionary is

```
NSMutableDictionary * myDict;
```

And your Array is

```
NSArray *myArray;

myArray = [myDict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

     if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {

          return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
     }
     if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {

          return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
     }

     return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Just use `NSNumber` objects instead of numeric constants.

BTW, this is taken from:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Dictionaries.html

Comment: Richard's proposal is more elegant than mine because NSNumber already comes with a suitable compare function but mine is probably more general.

Comment: In most cases, this solution will work fine, but what my answer has is the ability to support other types that respond to the `-compare:`

Comment: This will returns the key list , is there anyway that can get the dictionary directly , instead of having list of sorted keys in array

Comment: @Mr.G, no there is no way as NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionare are not sorted. You cannot sort them and expect them to be sorted afterwards.

Answer (score 27):

[NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has this neat method called `allKeys`.

If you want the array to be sorted though, [`keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/keysSortedByValueUsingComparator%3a) should do the trick.

Richard's solution also works but makes some extra calls you don't necessarily need:

```
// Assuming myDictionary was previously populated with NSNumber values.
NSArray *orderedKeys = [myDictionary keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
    return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}];
```

Comment: I edited my question, I thought it was implied the keys have to in order by key value

Comment: I'm asking for help on the sorting.

Comment: `keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:` will do this sorting.

Comment: could you write out a simple comparator block for ascending integers like I have in the question? I'm new to blocks and block structure.

Comment: I'm sure you can at least _try_ to use the method (documentation is linked).  If you have problems with it, come back with your coded attempt, I'd be more than happy to help you.

Comment: You are missing an 's' in your example code. (I can't edit for you because it is less than 6 letters)

Answer (score 16):

Here's a solution:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary; // initialize dictionary
NSArray *sorted = [[dictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [[dictionary objectForKey:obj1] compare:[dictionary objectForKey:obj2]];
}];
```

Comment: working correctly for strings starting with alphabates only, but when there is a string starting with number 10, its comming between first string starting with "A" and third string starting with "A"

Comment: Check the answer above, it's more intuitive and concise, even though this does the same thing.

Answer (score 14):

The simplest solution:

`[dictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]`

Comment: how to write that compare function

Comment: Please explain the compare method also.

Comment: For existing types (e.g. NSString), that method already exists.  For anything you create yourself, the method should return NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedSame, or NSOrderedDescending, depending on the order.  See the documentation for `compare:options:range:` for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Here i have done something like this:

```
NSMutableArray * weekDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sunday",@"Monday",@"Tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"Thursday",@"Friday",@"Saturday", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *dictArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < [weekDays count]; i++)
{
    dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i],@"WeekDay",[weekDays objectAtIndex:i],@"Name",nil];
    [dictArray addObject:dict];
}
NSLog(@"Before Sorting : %@",dictArray);

@try
{
    //for using NSSortDescriptor
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"WeekDay" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *descriptor = @[sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [dictArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptor];
    NSLog(@"After Sorting : %@",sortedArray);

    //for using predicate
    //here i want to sort the value against weekday but only for WeekDay<=5
   int count=5;
    NSPredicate *Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"WeekDay <=%d",count];
    NSArray *results = [dictArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:Predicate];

    NSLog(@"After Sorting using predicate : %@",results);
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorting cant be done because of some error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",exception] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert setTag:500];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```