# pulled a dictionary ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

here I try to sort a NSdictionary key and a value I find a method but it does not work.

`[detailEvent[@"occurences"] sortUsingSelector : @selector(compare:)];`

here is the source sorted

```
"occurences": [
    {
      "jour": "2014-07-27T00:00:00.000Z",
      "hour_start": "11:00:00",
      "hour_end": "18:00:00"
    },
    {
      "jour": "2014-07-26T00:00:00.000Z",
      "hour_start": "11:00:00",
      "hour_end": "18:00:00"
    },
    {
      "jour": "2014-07-25T00:00:00.000Z",
      "hour_start": "11:00:00",
      "hour_end": "18:00:00"
    }
```

I do not add all because it is very long

I want sorted by date so the key `jour`

is that there is another method to sort the dictionary?

thanks

Comment: This is a good example of a bad question my friend. You have to supply more info about how the compare function looks etc. Otherwise it's hard to help you.

Comment: Presumably the values for `jour` in your dictionaries are `NSString` instances? And you want to compare them as dates. So, you need to convert them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708742/getting-nsdictionary-keys-sorted-by-their-respective-values

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this will sort the dictionaries correctly

```
    NSArray *sorted = [detailEvent[@"occurences"] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *d1, NSDictionary *d2)
    {
        NSString *s1 = d1[@"jour"];
        NSString *s2 = d2[@"jour"];

        return( [s1 compare:s2] );
    }];
```

If you want them sorted so the most recent date is first, then change the order of the compare

```
        return( [s2 compare:s1] );
```

Comment: nope, values of jour are strings, you first have to convert them into nsdate objects

Comment: Yes @Eugene they are strings, strings that have a 4-digit year followed by a 2-digit month, followed by a 2-digit day, so in fact they will sort correctly as strings, and do not need to be converted to dates.

Comment: You can be a bit neater by changing the signature of the block to `^(NSDictionary *d1, NSDictionary *d2)` which saves doing the assignment at the top of the block.

Comment: @Abizern thanks for the tip. I guess I've been over-trained by `qsort` which is extremely picky about the function prototype.

Comment: In this case you aren't changing the prototype, you're just being more specific. The objects being passed are going to be dictionaries, you know that because it's your code. The block takes the actual objects but declares them to be `id` you're free to be more specific.