# Getting NSDictionary keys sorted by their respective values in Ascending order

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

I am trying to sort my NSDictionary as suggested at [Getting NSDictionary keys sorted by their respective values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708742/getting-nsdictionary-keys-sorted-by-their-respective-values]). Does the comparator block sort the keys  in ascending or descending order of values in NSDictionary? I want to display the keys according to ascending order of values. In other words, is the sorting operation done by the comparator block is in ascending or descending order?
Thank you.

Comment: Note that you **cannot** sort the actual dictionary entries.  Dictionary entries (as returned by a `for` loop on the dictionary) are in indeterminate order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code is in ascending order:

```
myArray = [myDict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
     if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
          return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
     }
     if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
          return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
     }
     return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

To descending order, switch:

```
return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
```

and

```
return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
```

Answer (score 2):

The resulting array will be in ascending order, where ascending is determined by the behavior of the comparator. (I.e. it might be different than what a casual observer would expect.)

The comparator receives two objects, often called `obj1` and `obj2`. If it returns `NSOrderedAscending` for a given pair of objects, then `obj1` will be ordered before `obj2` in the resulting array. If it returns `NSOrderedDescending` then `obj2` will be ordered before `obj1`. If it returns `NSOrderedSame`, then `obj1` and `obj2` will have arbitrary relative order in the resulting array.

By the way, a simple test program could have given you the answer.